# Use Excel 64-bit vs 32-bit Installation for running .xlam based macro from C# script

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am a novice when it comes to C#, but have created a script that will process report requests. The script will open up Excel, generate a report that is within an Excel Ribbon (.xlam), and then email that report to an end user.

I am having issues with one report in particular that crash the program as it runs into memory limitations with the 32-bit Excel installation, and receive the error:

> "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less
>   data or close other applications."

and other error messages until it crashes. It is crashing while it is attempting to regenerate the pivot cache of a pivot table.

Within the script, this is what I am using to open Excel:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

I have both 32-bit and 64-bit Excel installed on the machine, but it will default open the 32-bit version. Is there a way to force the use of 64-bit Excel? When I run the report through the ribbon without the use of the script, it will not generate in the 32-bit version, but will generate in the 64-bit version.

Comment: That is some heavy duty script... is it possible to reduce it's footprint?

Comment: Aren't Office 32bits and 64bits mutually exclusive for the same version?

Comment: Are you sure that you have both 32-bit and 64-bit excel installed - normally this is not allowed by the office installer

Comment: I would like to avoid that if possible, as all of the data that is being used to regenerate the PivotTable has been deemed necessary, for slicing/grouping/etc.

Comment: Both 32-bit and 64-bit excel are installed on the same machine.

Comment: If you have both 32 and 64 bits Excel, it probably means that version numbers are different (for example one Excel 2007 32bits and one Excel 2016 64bits)? If so you should be able to explicitly call the right one using `= new Excel.Application.16` or whatever the version number of your excel 64 bits is.

Comment: Different versions of Excel presumably? The installer shouldn't let you install 32 and 64 bit of the same version. Anyway, the answer is that you'd have to shell (or the equivalent) the relevant exe to get that.

Comment: Side-by-side different-bitness installs of the same version is not a supported scenario. Side-by-side different-bitness installs of **different** versions **can** work **if** the installations were made in chronological order (i.e. installed 2010 first, *then* 2016), but even that isn't a recommended scenario; non-chronological install **will** break stuff in unsupported ways. I'd just remove the 32-bit install.

Comment: Is it possible to remove just the 32-bit Excel without uninstall all of Office? The difficulty I have is I only have 64-bit Excel and 32-bit Office (all office apps)

Comment: Hard to tell, an hour later we still have no idea what versions are involved. I'd just wipe everything and clean-install the latest x64.

Comment: Other than knowing they are both Excel 2013, I'm not sure what else I can tell you. Is it possible to access the specific version somewhere?

Comment: Excel 64 bit - Microsoft Excel 2013 (15.0.4675.1001) MSO (15.0.4675.1002) 64-bit
Excel 32 bit - Excel 32 bit - Microsoft Excel 2013 (15.0.4569.1504) MSO (15.0.4953.1000) 32-bit